# How to create like button when you not eligable for a URL

Tags: facebook

I have just created a facebook business page and currently thus have no likes at minute. I want to create a 'Like box' for my website where people simply can click 'Like from my website'. The problem is I have no URL(href) to put into the 'Like' box field 'URL to Like' URL during the creation. I cant create a username(URL) for my business page keep getting message "you not eligable for a URL. In future you can..."

So what do I do? I can not even view my business facebook page without signing into facebook and searching for my page? Do I have to tell my customers to log into facebook search for us in the 'search box' in order to 'Like' us. Surely there must be away to put some URL into that 'Like box creation page' so that they can 'like' me directly from my website.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page should still have a url, of the form "facebook.com/pages/nameOfPage/randomNumber", which you can use.

Also, to get your own url, you only need to have 25 people like your page, can you suggest the page to some of your friends and coworkers?

Comment: Ah your right I believe there is a url you can put its in format 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/mybusiness/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/' so I put that url into the 'Like button href' and it should work?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but if it doesn't, you only need to have 25 people to like your page before you can make your own url anyway (you can like your own page by the way), so send out some emails to coworkers, friends, customers, parents, anyone willing to like your page.  They shouldn't need to be signed in, unless you somehow restricted the location or viewer age of the page.

Comment: The link did not work I will try to get some 25 friends to like it. Stupid that fb make you do this!

Comment: @daza: it's not that stupid, since otherwise you wouldn't be able to get a URL anyway after every possible URL was registered to a junk page.

Comment: @daza166 just a little update, I tried using the facebook.com/pages/nameOfPage/randomNumber url that Facebook assigns for new pages, and it worked for me.